# Match row entry from one data frame with column name from another

Tags: python, dataframe

[image: For some reason I am not able to make tables so uploading the picture]
I ran the following code but I am not able to get the access to the cell. how can I get access?

```
for i in df.iterrows():
    for j in df2.iterrows():
        if ((i['Player'] == j['Player']) and (i['Brand'] == df2.index)):
            df.loc[i,'Endorsements'] = j['?']
```

Comment: Why do you want to loop and not merge? Looping over dataframes is slow and inefficient.

Comment: I am comparing both the methods. I have to see the time difference in execution of both the methods.